# Ant design Button shape and color are not applied

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I installed ant design with npm

```
npm i --save antd
```

Then I used Button from their components like  this

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
```

```
<Button type="primary" shape="circle">
                    hey
                </Button>
```

The problem is that the button shape and type doesn't apply properly .
How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: import { Button } from 'antd/lib';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your entry point (where you have the `ReactDOM.render()`) add at the top of the file the following:

```js
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Or if you're using `create-react-app`, in your `src/App.css`:

```css
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

That will provide you the styling you need. Hope it helps!

---

[Getting Started with Antd - Official Docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started)
[Usage with Create React App - Official Docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Install-and-Initialization)